# How to upload an image from a domain to another domain under same server by php?

Tags: php, image, file, file-upload

I want to move an image from the folder `www.abc.com/upload/abc.jpg` to `www.def.com/upload/abc.jpg`. Here these two website have same cpanel of godaddy but their ftp details are different.. how can I move that image ?

```
  <?php
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "C:\inetpub\vhosts\def.com\upload\\" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 ?>
```

it is not working . But it will work when i am using `ftp_put()` function, this function needs ftp username and password.. i want to move the image without ftp details. how can i move it and is it possible?

Comment: You mentioned everything except the most important thing - are the two websites on the same physical server or not? If yes, then the answer is trivial. If not, then you mount the TARGET server's upload directory so the SOURCE one can see it. After that it's just copying one file to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
# Source domain code..
$save_dir = 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\abc.com\upload\abc.jpg' ;# Temporary save file in your source domain..
$url = "http://www.def.com/copy_upload_file.php"; # destination domain URL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "file"=> "@".$save_dir,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Add this file in your another domain..

```
# Destination domain file called as copy_upload_file.php
$path = 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\def.com\upload\'; # Write full path here
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "0";
    }
    else
    {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo "1";
        }
        else {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: thanks pankaj. which address will i assign to $save_dir?.
directory path or url path?

Comment: Sorry pankaj,, i didnt have the ftp details of another domain. so i cannt able to upload the copy_upload_file.php into the another domain..

Comment: @pankaj:  is both domains are on same server?

Comment: yes, both are under godaddy server, but both abc.com and def.com are different sites

Comment: If destination domain directory path having valid permission(777) then you can directly put file in that location other you should ask FTP credentials for client.

Comment: Already destination folder has the read/write permission and tried to move image by move_upload_file(), but it is not working